# What is the right location to store persistent objects?

Tags: java, xml, persistence, store

I am developing a medium Java desktop application, without using a database.
I am using xml, serializable objects, etc. to store the user/application data, but what is the right location to save these files to (system-independent)?

Comment: The right location is the database in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Why aren't you using a database? Use file-system database (like hsqldb) and an object relational mapping layer. You probably won't even need to write a mapping file of any kind, or arbitrarily make your classes serializable.

Store data in `%APPDATA%/appName` on windows, and probably `~/.appName` on linux.
`User/Library/Application/appName` could work on macs.

Comment: The question would still be the same, where do you store the hsqldb files.

Comment: ...no? You store data where your OS of choice *says* applications store data.

Comment: In that case it'll be the same whether you're using a (local) db or not then. Though most APIs, be it a db or files you create yourself, need a path as the input and the question is how do you get that path from a Java program.

Answer (score 2):

If you really don't want to store them in a data base take a look at the [Preferences API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/preferences/index.html) it is platform neutral.

Answer (score 1):

Most, if not all, OSes have a concept of a home directory where you end up having a lot of hidden configuration directories of one form or another. You could create a hidden directory under the users home directory and store your configuration/data files there.

Comment: It's a possible solution but I think not the best one. On unix it's often done, but if you're working with Windows there is the .Appdata-directory in the home directory.